# Erro de alocação de memória

Tags: c, script, memória, alocação

Estou criando um script em C para classificar um triângulo de acordo com os 3 lados passados. Para isso uso três variáveis distintas, `lado1`, `lado2` e `lado3`, como ilustra o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned short int lado1, lado2, lado3;

    printf("L1: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado1);
    printf("L2: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado2);
    printf("L3: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado3);

    if (lado1 < (lado2 + lado3) && lado2 < (lado1 + lado3) && lado3 < (lado1 + lado2)) {
        if ((lado1 == lado2) && (lado2 == lado3)) {
            printf("Triângulo equilátero");
        } else if ((lado1 != lado2) && (lado2 != lado3)) {
            printf("Triângulo escaleno");
        } else {
            printf("Triângulo isóceles");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Os lados informados não constituem um triângulo");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No entanto, quando tento compilar esse código é apresentado um erro de memória:

```
stack smashing detected: <unknown> terminated
```

O mesmo não acontece quando eu declaro uma string juntamente as outras três variáveis `lado1`, `lado2` e `lado3`. Assim, além das três variáveis tenho uma outra variável do tipo string `folk[90]` que não é utilizada dentro do código em momento nenhum, porém desta vez eu tenho o retorno desejado.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned short int lado1, lado2, lado3, folk[90];

    printf("L1: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado1);
    printf("L2: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado2);
    printf("L3: ");
    scanf("%i", &lado3);

    if (lado1 < (lado2 + lado3) && lado2 < (lado1 + lado3) && lado3 < (lado1 + lado2)) {
        if ((lado1 == lado2) && (lado2 == lado3)) {
            printf("Triângulo equilátero");
        } else if ((lado1 != lado2) && (lado2 != lado3)) {
            printf("Triângulo escaleno");
        } else {
            printf("Triângulo isóceles");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Os lados informados não constituem um triângulo");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O que eu desejo saber é a explicação para isso, porque isso ocorre? e como alocar a memória corretamente sem precisar dessa quarta variável?

*O compilador que eu uso é o* **gcc**

Comment: Não consegui replicar o erro. Os dois códigos funcionaram. passei os valores 3,4 e 5

Comment: @AugustoVasques mas qual compilador você usa?

Creio que seja algo com compilador

Comment: usei um container com [gcc](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro deve-se entender **o que é a pilha ou *stack***:

> O **stack é uma porção contígua de memória** reservada para empilhar os dados necessários durante a execução de blocos de código.
>
> Cada necessidade de alocação é um trecho do stack que vai sendo usado sempre em sequência... <sup>[1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15698/138506)</sup>

No caso do seu programa 3 variáveis do tipo `unsigned short` que tem seu tamanho definido em pelo menos 16 bits, ou 2 bytes, segundo a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

Sendo assim, podemos ver a pilha de seu programa, como:

[image: pilha]

***Stack Smashing*** é um tipo de ataque, um [*buffer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow), onde o programa tenta extrapolar o espaço (ou a *stack*), a ele reservado. <sup>[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416516/what-is-stack-smashing-c)</sup>

E foi isso que você fez, lendo 4 bytes em `scanf("%i", &lado3);`, ou seja, escrevendo um inteiro no endereço 0x05.

[image: prilha + execução]

Quando declarou `folk` (**NUNCA FAÇA ISSO** para um problema de execução, NUNCA MESMO), o programa teve folga, e pode não violar a pilha de execução, mas mesmo assim, há uma invasão de memória (bastante prejudicial igualmente).

Em resumo, **seu programa, ainda que rode, não funciona**.

Para consertar, alinhe o tipo de dado de entrada e a variável que recebe seu valor, como:

```
int lado1, lado2, lado3;
```

Comment: Desculpe cara, não entendi direito a parte do endereçamento, pareceu confuso para mim, sobretudo essa parte onde você fala sobre a leitura de 4bytes em `scanf("%i", &lado3)`, para mim cada uma das variáveis deveria armazenar um inteiro pequeno e não negativo, justamente por isso usei o `unsigned short int`. Agora entendi que tenho que me preocupar com a quantidade de bytes que cada tipo carrega.

Comment: Ainda assim, ao meu ver cada uma dessas variáveis deveria carregar 4bytes, certo?. Mas pelo que você me explicou não é dessa forma.

Você teria alguma referência que me ajudaria a entender isso, ou poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Entender os [tipos de dados em C](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Tipos_de_dados) é um começo.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` espera um `*int` para guardar o valor de `%i`, você fornece um `*unsigned short int`.

É provável que:

```
sizeof(int) == 4
sizeof(unsigned short int) == 2
```

Assim, o CPU vai escrever o resultado de tamanho quatro numa região de tamanho dois e `stack smashing detected: <unknown> terminated`

A array `folk[90]` pode estar sendo alocada logo depois de `lado3` na memória e, coincidentemente, impede que o valor seja escrito em região que quebra o código.

Troque o tipo das variáveis:

```
int lado1, lado2, lado3;
```

Ou o tipo do `scanf` para `%hu`:

```
scanf("%hu", &lado1);
```

Referência: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Mudar o tipo para `int` deu certo. Já a segunda forma não deu, o problema continuou o mesmo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Opa, foi um erro de digitação meu. O `%u` é para unsigned, o `%h` é para short. Você pode juntar os dois. Corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo com utilizando `scanf("%hu", &lado1);`

Comment: ótimo =) se você solucionou sua dúvida, por favor, escolha uma das respostas e marque a questão como respondida.